# HR Director was insulting, should I point it out before taking new job?

Tags: human-resources, job-change, unprofessional-behavior

During my hiring process, the HR Director said I was not worth the company's offer. That I would never get a better offer anywhere because I didn't have much experience (I had 15 years). They spoke in a demeaning, rude way to push me into not negotiating further. After I told them they were unprofessional and I ended the conversation and told them to keep the job offer, the company CEO called me up to apologize and explain that he and the team I would work with really valued me.

I ended up taking the job, but now within 6 months I have the better offer the HR Director said I would never get. I want to point out how wrong they were, because their words were soul-crushing at the time. I want the company to know that should never be a tactic taken with any new hire again.

Is there a way to do this? Or should I just leave without bringing it up. It was so painful at the time, it's hard to not want to point it out, because they were so wrong, but for a person with low self-esteem, a part of me believed it and nobody should have to feel that way.

Comment: Before you go to the effort, ask yourself these questions: What do you think it would accomplish? Do you think anything meaningful and long lasting would actually come out of it? What do you hope to gain by it?

Comment: I think it might help people understand that bad, bullying behavior should not be tolerated.

Comment: Help who understand? Who do you think will benefit from this? How will people find out about your actions and the results of those actions? Do you think that the company will tell all future job prospects about this? Who exactly do you hope will benefit and how do you imagine that they'll acquire this benefit?

Comment: I understand your desire to bring this to light, I'm just questioning the effectiveness of doing this and who will ultimately benefit from it, and how?

Comment: Maybe the HR Director will think twice about bullying others if they feel that my departure and my teams loss was partly due to their negative remarks that drove me to pursue other employment and prove them wrong.

Comment: I would like to say, directly, despite the HR Director saying I was not worth it, I demonstrated my value while here (many profitable projects completed) and now I am recognized for my value elsewhere. By being negative towards me, it really created an unsafe emotional feeling that never went away and drove me to another company. I want HR to understand and think twice about demoralizing job candidates.

Comment: People can find out about my actions/reactions through my resignation letter. Or maybe should I write an open letter to the 150 employees so all know?

Comment: Does HR insist on an exit interview when someone leaves the company?

Comment: @RR2 what was the real reason you are leaving the company? Leaving a company within 6 month is quite rare unless your were on the contract that is about to expire. Did you just try to prove that you worth more? Were you just offended by bullying by HR person? Was it something else?

Comment: HR part of reason. Being told one thing, but seeing no follow through by management again and again, another reason. Should I air out the reasons or let it go? Exit interview, usually. But I'd like to give one days notice and leave. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: One day notice? Well you are already burning the bridges then. Usually when you give a notice to your supervisor you are asked what is the reason. You can mention then. You can mention that on the exit interview if you really care and if there is going to be enough people saying that then company might take an action on HR person. But one day notice means you cannot stand them and most likely any your feedback is going to be ignored. You still can vent this out but you would achieve nothing positive.

Comment: What others say might be true and that's what might be happening everyday. but if there really is such an HR, who should let the managers know and how ? is there a mechanism about it? There is also a website called "Glassdoor" that you can usually find the review about big companies there from current and ex employees

Comment: @RR 2 Or you can send an anonymous letter to the managing director

Comment: If the position is better and the pay is higher, why not go there if you are unhappy with your current position? Regardless of your feelings about the HR director.

Comment: Good point. I guess HR's actions drove me to look for another job. The reason to take it is as you said, the good opportunity.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. The company surely wouldn't share your resignation letter with the remaining employees.
2. Writing an open letter to the remaining employees is a sure fire way to burn bridges, create animosity, and potentially damage whatever relationships you have left at this company.

It seems to me that your real motivation is to exact some kind of "karmic" revenge on the HR Director because of their insulting behavior. Such motivations never end well for anyone. My advice to you is to leave it alone.

You might mention it in an exit interview if there is one, and you might write an email to the CEO explaining it to them, but that's as far as I would take it.

In work, as in life, we'll encounter bullying, harassment, unfair treatment, demeaning behavior, etc., etc. You're allowing the behavior of the HR Director to hold power over you. Your skills are worth more than they told you and you've proven that by getting this new job. Stop letting the words of the HR Director hold power over you. Move on. You've proven to yourself that they were wrong. Let that be enough for you. You don't need to "get back" at them. Be bigger than that, be bigger than them.

Comment: Thank you joeqwerty. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: Just to add to this excellent answer - people who behave in the way this HR director did are highly unlikely to "learn a lesson" from being punished for their actions. Instead, if you make a scene on the way out the door, they'll just work hard to make it seem like **you** were the one with the problem. Bullies are expert deceivers. The HR director will have no problem dreaming up ways to discredit anything you say on the way out the door, and you won't be there to "argue" or counteract anything they do or say. You won't teach anyone a lesson, you'll just get yourself a bad reputation.

Answer (score 9):

> now within 6 months I have the better offer the HR Director said I would never get.

Does the new offer aligns with your future career goals and is a professional progression for you? If yes, sure go ahead and take it. You don't need to explicitly state it to the HR director.

> Or should I just leave without bringing it up.

Exactly do this. Considering your entire narration, *silently* moving would be your best response (revenge) as it gets the message across in the **boldest** way.

However, if the new offer is merely a pay increment (without any other form of career progression) and all it serves is to prove that you are worth more than you were valued, you need to think if it would be in the best interest of you career to take the offer or bring it up to the HR.

Merely mentioning about it to them without any intention of actually taking up the job won't do any good (even show you in weak light), and will end up burning bridges with a *co-worker*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue for any individual in this situation is about one’s own self -esteem.  If one has an adequate level of self-esteem these sort of situations will not be troubling and let alone an issue.  Yes, bullying and degrading comments are wrong but it’s the reality out there.  And one will face such again and again. Answer lies with our own self -esteem !